# Refresh a LWC component when a Page Layout is modified

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to update the lwc component when the "status" of the page layout is changed, how can I do it?

The button inside the lwc component should only be displayed on some occasions, depending on the "status" of the page layout.
But when I update the Page Layout, what can I do to make the lwc component update?

I can't think of how to solve this, any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [Make a Component Aware of Its Record Context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_record_context), and you use [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record), your component should automatically update when LDS (Lightning Data Service) detects the change.

```
import { wire, api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject/MyField';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId; // case sensitive, must be API, will give you the record id
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId' }) record;
  get shouldDisplayButton() {
    return getFieldValue(this.record, STATUS_FIELD) == 'SomeStatus';
  }
}
```

And on your button:

```
<lightning-button if:true={shouldDisplayButton} ...>
```

You can also hide/show the entire component, if you prefer, using [Dynamic Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5). Simply select the condition(s) for when the component should appear, and you can get this done with no extra code.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it